# Getting files on linux UBUNTU from Windows

Tags: linux, windows, operating-system

I am trying Linux UBUNTU on my windows system. I am knew in Linux UBUNTU.but I don't know that where I can find my files that were on windows 10.

Comment: Ubuntu in WSL or Ubuntu in a separate partition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In case you mean WSL Ubuntu:**

Your Harddrives are mounted under /mnt/. I like to create a symbolic links to them in my home folder. The should be named like so:

```
/mnt/c       # your C:\ drive
/mnt/s       # your S:\ drive
...
```

**In case you mean a Linux livesystem:**

If you use *a system with a graphical user interface*, somewhere in your filemanager you should see the respective drive. Click on it and it should auto-mount. Afterwards you should be able to access your files just as you would expect via the filemanager.

In case you're *in terminal mode (= you do not have any graphical user interface)*, things might get a little strange from a beginner's perspective. In this case I would recommend that you make yourself familiar with the rough structure of the linux filesystem and the commands `mount`, `umount` and `sudo`. Generaly said you will have to do the same thing your filemanager does for you. You mount the drive somewhere in the filesystem tree and then access the folder:

```
mount /dev/<drive> <directory> # mount your drive into the fs tree
cd <directory>                 # switch to that folder
ls                             # should display your drive's content
```